# Can I set the Blue Palace to be my home through console commands in Skyrim?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, pc

Can the Blue Palace or any other house ownership be changed to become mine in Skyrim through console commands?

Answer (score 3):

Yes and no. You can use "setownership" in the console to make the target item belong to you, but you will not get all the functionality a proper house provides: your spouse will not be able to move in, you won't be able to purchase upgrades, storage will likely not be safe, etc.

Comment: Wouldn't you need the Blue Palace ID for that? I think that code is specific for movable objects.

Comment: It's certainly not specific to movable objects, you can claim a bed and get the well-rested bonus from sleeping in it, or claim a container so taking items from it is not theft.